# поиск текста в поле Image SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица с полем Image куда я загружаю данные с файлов (doc, xml и тп.) через приложение.
Нужно найти, к примеру, заданное слово в полях с данными и вывести id, которая относится к данной строке.
Пробую найти слово запросом:

```
SELECT id
FROM Test
WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR (MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), [File_Content])) LIKE N'%Регистрация%';
```

Но результат не находит такого слова, хотя оно есть. 
Но! Слово на англ раскладке прекрасно находит и выводит результат с id.
Вполне возможно проблема в том, что старые данные были неправильно внесены в таблицу и не состыковка в Юникоде.
Пробую внести данные вручную:

```
insert into Test(File_Name,File_Ext,File_Content)
values('File', 'doc', CONVERT(IMAGE, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), N'Регистрация Где-то здесь должно быть слово "this"')')))
```

В таком случае строки со словами находит и на русской и на англ раскладке.

Метод, с помощью которого вношу данные в таблицу через приложение:

```
private void UploadFile()
        {
            string filePath;
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filePath = fileDialog.FileName;
                string fileName = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);                               //Получаем имя файла                
                string fileExtension = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);                           //Получаем расширение файла
                byte[] binaryFile;                                                                                  //Массив для хранения бинарных данных файла
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    binaryFile = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(binaryFile, 0, binaryFile.Length);
                }

                cs = cs.LoadFile();
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs.ToString()))
                {
                    try
                    {                            
                        conn.Open();
                        //Запрос на добавление сообщения в таблицу
                        string querryUpload = "insert into Test(\"File_Name\", \"File_Ext\", \"File_Content\") " +
                                            "values(@fileName, @fileExt, @binData)";                            
                        using (SqlCommand cmdAddMess = new SqlCommand(querryUpload, conn))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                cmdAddMess.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", fileName);
                                cmdAddMess.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileExt", fileExtension);
                                cmdAddMess.Parameters.AddWithValue("@binData", binaryFile);
                                SqlDataReader rezultAddMess = cmdAddMess.ExecuteReader();
                                if (!rezultAddMess.HasRows /*&& string.IsNullOrEmpty(sendMessageTextBox.Text)*/)               //Проверка на отправку сообщения
                                    MessageBox.Show("Сообщение отправлено!");
                                else
                                    MessageBox.Show("ошибка отправления!");
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Выберите получателя!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Подскажите, как правильно вносить данные с файлов, чтобы можно было потом корректно найти текст внутри этих данных поля Image или как правильно искать данные, может я делаю что-то не так

Comment: как по мне - извлекать текст из файлов, хранить его отдельно и использовать полностекстовый поиск.

Comment: @teran само собой это проще всего) но нужно чтобы данные с файлов хранились в поле Image, и в нем искать

Comment: К сожалению, помочь не могу, но сейчас восстанавливаю старое приложение (еще не было .docx). Там я тоже хранил .doc в Image. Вы не пытались загрузить в Word (VBA) непосредственно из Image, минуя преобразования в файл?